# Where's the Gnome Nanny blacklist repo?

Tags: parental-controls

I have been looking over the Internet for the Gnome Nanny blacklist repo, and I am not able to find it.

In the Help for the application there's a repo called Nanny Central DansGuardian Clone but the application looks for a Nanny Central repo that I don't know where to find.

I am really needing this information to setup the application.

Thank you.

Comment: I opened a bug report here: [Bug in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nanny/+bug/788107) also there's a bounty for this, let's see who gets this resolved :)

Answer (score 4):

http://projects.gnome.org/nanny/

There is a download link on there, that leads to this:
http://projects.gnome.org/nanny/data/nbl/nanny.nbl which I believe is what you are looking for.

EDIT: try this:
http://static.nannycentral.org/v/nannycentral/blacklists/blacklist.json

EDIT 2: Installed it myself. Everything seems as dead as hell. You should try something like safesquid, because Gnome Nanny is hopeless.

Comment: Nah, it's not that one (I already tried that one), take a look at this screenshot: http://img195.imageshack.us/i/nannyr.png/

Comment: @Heiner Valverde Updated. Thank you for providing more info.

Comment: Yeah I think I may give a try to safesquid, Gnome Nanny is totally buggy and the developers doesn't appear with information about this bug :(

Answer (score 0):

Browsing the nanny source code shows an url in Importer.py

http://urlblacklist.com/cgi-bin/commercialdownload.pl?type=download&file=smalltestlist

I do not know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you Manfred but this is not what Gnome Nanny looks for :(